# TypeScript - generic function collapses types from some generic interfaces to "unknown"

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, mapped-types

I have a function that merges the results of multiple API requests (if none of them has an error):

```
mergeAPIResults({ data: 123 }, { data: 'test' }) // produces: { data: [ 123, 'test' ] }

mergeAPIResults({ data: 123 }, { error: 'failed' }) // produces: { error: 'failed' }
```

The real world use case would be `useQuery()` from [React Query](https://tanstack.com/query/latest/), but I tried to simplify the following example to a bare minimum. The problem is, as soon as I extend the original interface or try to use a duck typed interface, TypeScript collapses the resulting types to `unknown`.

Here's the working part:

```
interface APIResult<DataType> {
  data?: DataType
  error?: any
}

// mapped type - transforms [ number, string, ... ] into [ APIResult<number>, APIResult<string>, ... ]
type WrapWithAPIResults<T extends any[]> = {
  [K in keyof T]: APIResult<T[K]>
}

function mergeAPIResults<T extends any[]>(...apiResults: WrapWithAPIResults<T>): APIResult<T> {
  const error = apiResults.find(r => r.error)?.error

  if (error) {
    return { error }
  } else {
    return { data: apiResults.map(r => r.data) as T }
  }
}


const mergeTest = mergeAPIResults({ data: 123 }, { data: 'test' })
// ✅ results in type: APIResult<[number, string]>

const mergeTest2 = mergeAPIResults(mergeTest, { data: 456 })
// ✅ results in type: APIResult<[[number, string], number]>
```

And here's where the issue comes up:

```
interface ExtendedAPIResult<DataType> extends APIResult<DataType> {
  extraData: string
}

const extApiResult: ExtendedAPIResult<string> = { data: 'test', extraData: 'blah' }

const mergeTestError = mergeAPIResults({ data: 456 }, extApiResult)
// ❌ results in type: APIResult<[number, unknown]>
// expected type: APIResult<[number, string]>
```

Removing `extraData` from the interface doesn't help. Creating an identical interface `interface APIResult2<DataType> { data?: DataType, error?: any }` doesn't help either. However, using `UseQueryResult` from [useQuery()](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tanstack/react-query) actually *does* work(?!?).

```
const mergeTestRQ = mergeAPIResults({ data: 456 }, useQuery({ queryFn: () => true }))
// ✅ results in type: APIResult<[number, boolean]>
```

I must be missing something. What could be the problem?

Comment: FYI, disabling `strictNullChecks` makes it work as expected. [playground](https://tsplay.dev/mAgKPw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `APIResult` has its fields as optional fields and when you pass something typed as `APIResult` your mapped type doesn't work as expected. Two possible solutions:

1. Disable [strictNullChecks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks) tsconfig option and  everything work as expected.
2. Better solution:
   Make your mapped type to turn the type of the element to non nullable version first, which can be achieved using [NonNullable](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) builtin utility type:

```
type WrapWithAPIResults<T extends unknown[]> = {
  [K in keyof T]: APIResult<NonNullable<T[K]>>;
};
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIAUCSAlCBnAVwBswAeAETjDgBUBPABwgD5kBvAKGWQBMq4A-AC5klavSYBuLsmhQA9lGHI4IOtIC+HDgHodyALZwGTHsjCMUAWnNRVeGIoN5kAbWQgCBgEbQANMh4YFCgAOYBAHRRyAC6yKBg8m5oWLiEJKSePtDMARg4+MRkQSEgobnIURGxHBZMyADqdgwNwGAAFvlpRXikNLIAHpAgPC4EIADWIPIA7iCuMawAvOwyrgDS8SDIExB08jDINDEiXYUZAHLyIBfERHDeRBB9G4vMmtIcMOMIYMDXhmgoQgZ3SYF6-QgQwgIzGk2mcwWzAAFDIqsZgN0SHgRE1jK0OqCen1mBwAJSnVLnMg0VicbgIa5BWRQBRQZArDFY8ERGCgHjI5FQMkc1hQCJyRRkgQS1mKT7cYCHZGS4WrbjcKAQMAEKDbNgstnIDTSbgaWREPAoekarU6vXsXj8ERc6l4CJGBiCtVLMURPjUEVwFz9E0yLRaDiMkDMgxAiA0fBgDmAqDAonY5EGgNwEQARgATABmY0BbPO5AAckgQUrxrJ0j0yEAoOTILVglygcyWSkFMGkVxZXxQAIlMKLbTR2PxxNBAspuNpkFUjvIxfA2dgMtO6giAAsAFYAGz1xv6VvtnpbbtMXvcgeDrzD0fBccBIfQCccBLQeBIZAAKLQiMEA8BmZBiLQlisFCwyjCkfZFBQ-ASCw6qDMEcCQSIY5lJok5MsmsGoAwmLUiIQFwaB4GkLh5QpjaOYiNWSaVn4MiwXY2FVo8cDtGxHBhgRMbJuuCZJgBcrsisYngXgWY7rmyCHieGgBMRpHcg2HBAA)

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Could you explain why the optional fields matter? I'm still confused the original interface works, but the extended one doesn't, even though both have the same optional `data` field.

Comment: I believe it is because your generic parameter `T` isn't directly equal to `apiResults`, but to `WrapWithAPIResults`. And in the `WrapWithAPIResults` if you replace `APIResult` with `ExtendedAPIResult` the issue with the return type is also fixed, though will raise the error by passing just `APIResult` to a function. Overall, I think the issue is that typescript can't fully infer the type since, `T != apiResults`